# Django 'django.contrib.redirects' is weird on 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm developing a site and there are some old URLs to redirect. I use something like this:

```
    url(r'^i/personagens/*(?:index\.php)*', 'whatever.views.legacy_personanges_home', name='legacy_personanges_home'),
```

and in the views

```
def legacy_personanges_home(request):
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/bio/')
```

While developing I collect old urls and run them on a simple verifier to check my redirects and old pages are handled accordingly. Here it is:

```
host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
oks = 0
bads = 0
good_codes = [200,301,302]
legacy_urls = [
    '/i/personagens/index.php',
    '/i/personagens/',
    '/i/personagens/index.php?x=1',
]

import urllib2

for path in legacy_urls:
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(host + path)
        request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        print response.getcode(), path, '-->', response.geturl()
        if response.getcode() in good_codes:
            oks += 1
        else:
            bads += 1
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.code, path
        bads += 1

total = oks + bads
print 'OK: %d/%d' % (oks, total)
print 'BAD: %d/%d' % (bads, total)
```

Response:

```
200 /i/personagens/index.php --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/bio/
200 /i/personagens/ --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/bio/
200 /i/personagens/index.php?x=1 --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/bio/
OK: 3/3
BAD: 0/3
[Finished in 2.7s]
```

Nice! urlopen() follows redirects and the response should be a 200. geturl() shows me the final url.

Later I discovered there were lots of different new urls to redirect, so I decided to use the Django Redirects framework. I installed it and put those very 3 urls there to redirect to my '/bio/' new url.

**The Weird part:**

I opened `http://127.0.0.1:8000/personagens/index.php` in the browser, it worked, I could see the 301 there and the following 200.

I ran again the same verifier:

```
404 /i/personagens/index.php
404 /i/personagens/
404 /i/personagens/index.php?x=1
OK: 0/3
BAD: 3/3
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

I could see the logs

```
[28/Feb/2014 13:00:41] "HEAD /i/personagens/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 0
[28/Feb/2014 13:00:41] "HEAD /i/personagens/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0
[28/Feb/2014 13:00:41] "HEAD /i/personagens/index.php?x=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 0
```

I changed the HEAD to GET just in case... still not working

thanks in advance

Comment: When I installed the redirects framework I removed the urlpattern and the view to make sure the redirects was doing the job.

Comment: I'm using the builtin server. Running it in 0.0.0.0:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't change anything